# Docker 2.4 on macos mounts volumes not properly when "use gRPC for file sharing" enabled

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-compose, mysql-8.0

After I've updated the macos docker app to the latest (2.4.0.0) version I can't start the mysql service in my container when  "use gRPC for file sharing" is enabled and the /var/lib/mysql/ directory is mounted as a volume on my local machine. I than get this error in mysql error.log:

```
Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data dictionary ('0').
```

Fortunately, when the option "use gRPC for file sharing" is unchecked in the docker app settings/preferences, then my persisted /var/lib/mysql/ volume doesn't cause any problems at container startup/built and the container works fine.

But how to persist my mysql data properly with this new feature enabled? I assume it brings some perfomance advantages(?)

The steps as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150016/4721232) are not working. When I start the container whit the gRPC option enabled and an empty mysql database and then import a sql dump then everything works fine, but as soon as I make /var/lib/mysql/ as a volume, then I get this error again.

I've tried to isolate only the particular database (/var/lib/mysql/mydb) and to mount this as a volume instead of the whole mysql directory. And in deed, the mysql server starts properly, but now my database is not working - queries don't output anything / can't find any data or tables/columns in the "mydb" database.

---

Answer (score 2):

This is an application bug that needs to be solved by Docker. Please use the [github issues](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues) for these. Two issues have already been opened for this, so it would be best to follow them and/or provide additional steps to reproduce the issue in your scenario there:

- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4959
- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4964